# How can I construct a process tree?

Tags: python-3.x, process, tree, hierarchy

I have a list of processes.

I want to take this process list and organize it in a tree structure so that I can easily visualize parent-child relationships, and identify suspect or unwanted processes.

However, I am struggling to come up with an algorithm or pseudo code to create the process tree.

I can't use tools like pstree because I'm dealing with textual process logs.

Can you point me to any data structures or algorithms that can be applied to this problem?

Here's some sample code to illustrate the problem:

```
class Process():
    def __init__(self, name, pid, parent_pid):
        self.name = name
        self.pid = pid
        self.ppid = parent_pid

# assume you have a process list with these fields:
# process name, PID, Parent PID
proc1 = Process("one", 1, 0)
proc2 = Process("two", 2, 1)
proc3 = Process("three", 3, 2)
proc4 = Process("four", 4, 3)
proc5 = Process("five", 5, 3)
proc6 = Process("six", 6, 2)

# append each process to a list
process_list = [proc1, proc2, proc3, proc4, proc5, proc6]

for each_proc in process_list:
    # how do I do this?
    get_child_processes()
    display_as_tree()

"""
Desired output:

one
|
|__two
   |
   |__three
   |   |
   |   |_four
   |   |
   |   |_five
   |
   |__six


"""
```

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this problem, I came to a solution via a depth first search algorithm.

Here is a simplified example of the code with output:

```py
# Make a dictionary consisting of parent processes child nodes
# This is basically an adjacency graph
graph = {
    'proc1' : ['proc2','proc3'],
    'proc2' : ['proc4', 'proc5'],
    'proc3' : ['proc7'],
    'proc4' : [],
    'proc5' : ['proc6'],
    'proc6' : [],
    'proc7' : []
}

# Set to keep track of visited nodes.
visited = set()

# Use the depth first search algorithm to construct the process tree
def depth_first_search(visited, graph, node, padding):
    if node not in visited:
        display = padding + node
        print (display.strip())
        padding += "..."
        visited.add(node)
        for neighbour in graph[node]:
            depth_first_search(visited, graph, neighbour, padding)

# Execute depth first search function
padding = "".strip()
depth_first_search(visited, graph, 'proc1', padding)
```

Output:

```
$ python proc_tree.py

proc1
...proc2
......proc4
......proc5
.........proc6
...proc3
......proc7
```

Answer (score -1):

why not just use a tree with only one father and descendants? (that's a real question you must have thought about, right?)

Comment: I did consider this, and it is not an acceptable solution for my use case.